# vb.net How to change the selected item of comboBox which is datagridview column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

how i can change the item of combo box that is a column of data grid view according to the combobox that is present in the form

```
      Dim productGrid as DataGridView
      Dim objProductGroup As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        With productGroup
            .HeaderText = "ProductGroup"
            .Name = "ProductGroup"
            .ReadOnly = True
            .Items.Add("Server")
            .Items.Add("Standalone")
        End With
        .Columns.Add(objProductGroup)
```

I have to select the objProductGroup combo box as per combo box that is on the form

```
    dim box1 as ComboBox
    box1..Items.Add("Server")
    box1.Items.Add("Standalone")
```

When i will select the box1 item Server then objProductGroup comboBox should automatically updated.

Comment: You create `objProductGroup` as a TextBoxColumn ... Below that, you using the variable `productGroup`. I'm not sure if you meant to use the objProductGroup variable in your with statement - but if you did, try declaring a DAtaGridViewComboboxColumn instead - you'll get better results!

Comment: sorry, it was typing mistake. i corrected the question, Yes i declared as DataGridViewComboBox. Which line of code will be used to change the item in comboBox.

Comment: You handle the SelectedIndexChanged event of the Combobox and then change the required combobox programatically in that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following  code will change your DataGridView's CurrentRow Column "ProductGroup" to the value you selected in `box1`. I am not sure if you were trying to set ALL of the rows to the value in the combobox or just the current row.

In any case, you may want to test if the CurrentRow actually has any cells. For example:

`If Not productGrid.CurrentRow Is Nothing Then [Execute the value changed]`

For the sake of making it work after I selected a row, this is the code I used:

```
Private Sub box1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles box1.SelectedIndexChanged
    productGrid.CurrentRow.Cells("ProductGroup").Value = box1.SelectedItem
End Sub
```